# Write data to one file, numerous times

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a very long data needs to be analyzed, and so I've decided to write it to a file several times during the code, and store it as a .csv file.

I've tried the following:

```
fid = fopen('c:\temp\results\final.csv','w'); %fid is a global variable
```

**In another file do the following**

```
    string_data = strcat(fullFileName, '_' ,stim_vec,'_THD.csv');
    fprintf(fid, '\n%s\n', string_data);
    dlmwrite('c:\temp\results\final.csv', THD, '-append');

    string_data = strcat(fullFileName, '_' ,stim_vec,'_phase_diff.csv');
    fprintf(fid, '\n%s\n', string_data);
    dlmwrite('c:\temp\results\final.csv', phase_diff, '-append');
```

**And again in the first file**

```
fclose(pid)
```

My problem is that data arriving from dlmwrite command only being written once, I think that fprintf data overrun it - but couldn't figure out how...

Can someone please assist me?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you'd want to do `fid = fopen('c:\temp\results\final.csv','a');`, that won't erase the file and just append the data

Comment: Yes! that did the trick - Thanks!

Comment: dlmwrite handles file io internally, you shouldn't use it in conjunction with fopen/fwrite. to append use the -append option when calling dlmwrite. also rtfm.